# Callback functions with server actions

Tags: forms, next.js, callback, server-action

I am just getting myself familiar with server actions in Next.js 14 app router, server actions are generally used to make post requests to the server ... Is there a way server actions can trigger a function on the client, the idea is to have something similar to React query `onSucess` and `onError`, those functions can be triggered based on the state the response to an API, let's assume a user makes a sign up request using server actions with an already existing email, and in my application functionality I need to trigger a toast notification to let the user know the email is already in use, any idea how to implement this...

This is a snippet in Next.js docs how we can use `useFormState` to get a return value from the server action, this can be reworked with a `useEffect` to trigger a function on the client, but i really do no want a `useEffect` solution.

```js
export function AddForm() {
const [state, formAction] = useFormState(createTodo, initialState)
    return (
        <form action={formAction}>
            <label htmlFor="todo">Enter Task</label>
            <input type="text" id="todo" name="todo" required />
            <SubmitButton />
            <p aria-live="polite" className="sr-only">
              {state?.message}
            </p>
        </form>
    )
}
```

I can confirm `useFormStatus` with `useEffect` works but I am hoping for a more optimized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a more optimized solution, but it's different. You could use useTransition. In this example, `signUp` is a server action. Within the `handleSignup` function, you can set states or parse `result` to trigger toasts and so on.

```
import { useTransition } from "react";

const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

const handleSignup = form.handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    startTransition(async () => {
        const result = await signUp(data);
    });
});

return (
    <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={handleCreateProspect}>
...
```